# Why doesn't NgForOf directive in Angular work with union types?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my component I have a property array defined like this:

```
array: number[] | string[] = ['1', '2'];
```

And in template I'm iterating over the elements of this array using ngFor:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of array">
  {{element}}
</div>
```

But compiler throws this error:

```
error TS2322:
Type 'number[] | string[]' is not assignable to
type '(number[] & NgIterable<number>) | null | undefined'.
```

I don't understand how and why Angular infers that the type of property `array` should be `number[] & NgIterable<number>` in this case.

I know I can get rid of the error by using `$any()` inside the template, or setting `angularCompilerOptions.strictTemplates` inside `tsconfig.json` to `false`, but I would like to avoid doing that if not necessary.

I also don't like the idea of changing the type of the `array` property to `(number | string)[]` because that would be wrong, I want `array` to contain only numbers, or only strings.

Comment: You're not the only one having [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/49310).

Comment: Does `array: Array<number | string> = ['1', '2'];` work? I know it's not the same

Comment: you could use `$any(...)` in a template as a temporary solution untill the issue is resolved. or maybe define type of your array as (string | number)[]

Comment: It looks like a compiler issue to me, as if you swap `number[] | string[]` with `string[] | number[]` the error becomes `Type 'string[] | number[]' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<string>'.`, so it looks like only the first type of the union is taken and the other types are always excluded in the structural directive. The structural directive type checking seems fairly okay though: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d887d69f241f67dd77c8533f7eed08d6397f98a8/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts#L146

Comment: Looks like a candidate for a bug report

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed a bug in Angular. `NgFor` code is correct, your code is also correct. See example below, it compiles just fine:

```
type NgIterable<T> = T[] | Iterable<T>;

const f = <T, U extends NgIterable<T> = NgIterable<T>>(param: (U & NgIterable<T>) | undefined | null) => false;

const a: string[] | number[] = ['1'];

window.console.info(f(a));
```

Angular transforms templates into TS, it generates "glue" code for your templates and this is where the bug is. Angular has to "infer" template variable types itself (e.g. by analysing AST) and then feed it into generated code.

In your example Angular incorrectly infers type as `number[]`.

Then somewhere in generated code they have temp variable or constant or property that has desired (and incorrect) type which is `(number[] & NgIterable<number>) | null | undefined`, e.g.:

```
//...
// templateVar type is "string[] | number[]", it comes from your code
// does not compile
const temp: (number[] & NgIterable<number>) | null | undefined = templateVar; 
ngForInstance.ngForOf = temp;
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a getter that "cast" your array

```
  get castArray()
  {
    return this.array as NgIterable<number|string>
  }
```

And use `castArray` in the *ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let element of castArray">
   {{element}}
</div>
```

But really I feel that it's an "ugly" approach.

Answer (score 1):

For an array, you can make a union type using `array: Array<number|string>;`. Union types never have worked well in TS (as far as I know), but with simple types a|b it should work ok, I think.

As a sidenote, don't call your array `array`. This is a reserved keyword and is bound to cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting `issue` and you can easily solve it with `typescript 4.9` typing feature `satisfies`:

```
array = ['1', '2'] satisfies (number[] | string[]);
```

And now there is no error anymore.